# SUM value group by columns but do not 'aggregate' possible?

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift

I want to sum the number of times thresholds were reached according to 2 different values: date and item.

Redshift gives me an error asking for more columns in the group by (that I do not want in the group by: "column must appear in the group by clause or be used in an aggregate function").

Another issue that would arise is that the code would aggregate my columns and I want to duplicate the SUM number.

What I have

```
|------------|--------|------------|
| item_type  | date   |thresh_rchd |
|------------|--------|------------|
|    baby    |monday  |      2     |
|------------|--------|------------|
|    tom     |monday  |      6     |
|------------|--------|------------|
|    baby    |monday  |      8     |
|------------|--------|------------|
|    baby    |tuesday |      4     |
|------------|--------|------------|
```

What I want:

```
|------------|--------|------------|-------------|
| item_type  | date   |thresh_rchd |total thresh |
|------------|--------|------------|-------------|
|    baby    |monday  |      2     |     10      |
|------------|--------|------------|-------------|
|    tom     |monday  |      6     |      6      |
|------------|--------|------------|-------------|
|    baby    |monday  |      8     |     10      |
|------------|--------|------------|-------------|
|    baby    |tuesday |      4     |      4      |
|------------|--------|------------|-------------|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try like below by using window function

```
select item_type, date, thresh_rchd, 
       sum(thresh_rchd) over(partition by item_type, date) as total_thresh
from tablename
```

Comment: seems to be working perfectly! will keep using over and partition by when group by doesnt cut it! thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.item_type,t1.date,t1.thresh_rchd,t2.total
from <table> t1
inner join
(
select item_type,date,sum(thresh_rchd) total from <table>
group by item_type,date) t2
on t1.item_type=t2.item_type
and t1.date=t2.date
```